# Facebook Login for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to open a facebook gallery if is logged in in facebook else I asked for the facebook login in android using facebook sdk and I wrote this code:

```
Session.openActiveSession(FbGallery.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        System.out.println("Session:::"+session.toString());

        if(session.isOpened()){
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(
                    new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(FbGallery.this, "user_photos"));
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Session is opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gone to else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

It works nicely and gets login page if is not logged in but if is logged in then it runs the code recursively ie. the toast message 'Session is opened' up here.

What is the reason. I can't understand..

Answer (score 1):

private void onClickRequest() 
    {

```
    if (this.session.isOpened() && session!=null) 
    {
        shareDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        shareDialog.setTitle("Post ON Wall");
        shareDialog.setMessage("Wait..........");
        shareDialog.setCancelable(false);

        System.out.println("Already Logged In");

        if (session.isOpened()) {
            // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 


            {
            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (user != null) {

                System.out.println(user.getId()+user.getName()+"........................");
                id=user.getId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), session.getAccessToken(), 100).show();
            }
            }
            });
            }
        //postPhoto();
    } else {
        StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback() {
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                if (exception != null) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Failed Login")
                            .setMessage(exception.getMessage())
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                            .show();
                    MainActivity.this.session = createSession();
                }
            }
        };
        pendingRequest = true;
        MainActivity.this.session = createSession();


        this.session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
        .setCallback(callback).setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO).setPermissions(""));




    }
```

Comment: Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    
         
          session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
          MainActivity.this.session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
          
          android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();

Comment: Thanks.. I changed some of your code and it worked... :)

Comment: One thing to say. Your code and my code are almost same.. Y didn't my code work out???

Answer (score 0):

```
if (session.isOpened())
 {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Login",500).show();
 onClickRequest();
 } 
else 
  {
  onClickRequest();
     session = createSession();
  }
```