# Facebook Graph API Integration into my API

Tags: android, ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an API that will be used solely for a mobile app, the mobile app allows users to log in via facebook and grant the app permission to access the users facebook friends list and post on their wall.

However I have some confusion as to where I integrate into the API and where the app developers integrate. I assume the login with facebook part is done by the app developers, who then pass the facebook access token into the API for it to store/retrieve friend list and make posts on the users wall.

Am I correct in assuming this? And if so can I test my part the implementation by retrieving friends list without having the app developers do their part first?

Thanks

Comment: this is code for facebook login
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962865/facebook-login-for-android/22963902#22963902

Answer (score 0):

First you have to register your app with your facebook id in developer.facebook.com then you will get the app id which you have to put into facebook login that generate access token for the process

Comment: Yes, this would be for the app developers, however I am developing an API in PHP for the app developers. This will be the main API for the app, however they will use facebook API to integrate social aspects as well as allow users to login through it. My question is do I make the requests from my API to facebooks graph API after their app has been granted permission from the user and retrieved an authentication token, or do they have to make all the requests from the app and then pass the response into my API?

Answer (score 0):

To make any call to the Facebook API you need an app ID. after receiving it, you can make calls to the API from your controller using the Facebook php SDK